# How to troubleshoot occasional Apache 500 errors?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, centos6, troubleshooting, 500-error

I have GET and POST requests, both HTTP 1.0 and 1.1, to diverse URLs, mostly running Wordpress(1), which occasionally fail with a 500(2). No user has ever encountered a 500 themselves, nor have visitors ever reported one. But they do show up in the logs. Most of the time, the error is in connection with a bot request (decent bots too, including googlebot, bingbot). All User-Agents that do not seem to be a bot include the *Linux* string.

The only common thread I can infer across all these 500s is the bot/linux UAs connection.

**What else could I try in order to figure out why these specific requests are failing?**

```
16Gb RAM (rarely uses up more than 3GB)
8 cores, rarely goes above 0.50
Apache 2.2.15
mod_fgcid 2.3.7
CentOS 6.4
Kernel 2.6.32

TimeOut 60
KeepAlive on
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       2
MinSpareServers    2
MaxSpareServers   5
ServerLimit      120
MaxClients      120
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>

Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_alias_module (shared)
 authn_anon_module (shared)
 authn_dbm_module (shared)
 authn_default_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 authz_owner_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_dbm_module (shared)
 authz_default_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 ext_filter_module (shared)
 mime_magic_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 vhost_alias_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 speling_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 substitute_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 cache_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
 disk_cache_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 cloudflare_module (shared)
 sed_module (shared)
 security2_module (shared)
 unique_id_module (shared)
 fcgid_module (shared)
 evasive20_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
```

*1) Some of these Wordpress sites are running [W3TC](http://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/), others are not. Some vhosts are running Magento, but they get so few 500s I'm gonna write them off as bad requests.*

*2) I have setup log monitoring and I get emailed when 500s occur.*

**PS: If this question gets moved to Wordpress.SO or Webmasters.SO I might as well delete it. I will never get a decent answer there...**

Comment: Anything in the Apache error log when these happen?

Comment: Yes, the 500s I'm basing my entire question around.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the log entries, then?

Comment: `176.57.141.193 - - [28/Oct/2013:18:16:16 +0000] "GET /2010/06/blog-post/ HTTP/1.1" 500 55894 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0"`

Comment: That's the access log.  Can you check the error log?

Comment: You will likely find a `PHP Fatal` error in you PHP error log related to this error.  PHP errors may be in the Apache error log or wherever the `error_log` directive in your `php.ini` puts them.

Comment: I've found nothing in the logs with matching timestamps to any of the 97 errors in the access logs.